# Android Kotlin RecyclerView Image not changing on click event

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a ReyclerView, when you click on "more info" the item is expanded. I want to add an image when this more info is clicked but when I set the image inside onClickListener the image does not show in the recycler view. How can I set the Image from onClickListener?

when i put the image outside the onClickListener the image is visible but I do not want to do that since it will make lots of requests to the api as my recycler view list is large.

```kotlin
holder.moreinfo.setOnClickListener {
            restaurant.expandable = true

            var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
                    restaurant.latitude +
                    "," +
                    restaurant.longitude +
                    "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false" +
                    "&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C" +
                    restaurant.latitude +
                    "," +
                    restaurant.longitude +
                    "&key=API_KEY"

            Log.e("url", url)
            Glide
                .with(holder.itemView.context)
                .load(url)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.map)

            notifyItemChanged(position)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Glide
    .with(holder.itemView.context)
    .load(url)
    .addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            notifyItemChanged(position)
            return true
        }
    })
    .centerCrop()
    .into(holder.map)
```